# What is the architecture CAD app that was shown in the iPad Pro video

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, ios-appstore

In [the video](https://www.apple.com/media/us/ipad-pro/2016/8242d954_d694_42b8_b6b7_a871bba6ed54/films/feature/ipadpro-9-7inch-feature-cc-us-20160321_1280x720h.mp4) for the iPad Pro, there was an architecture app that was shown several times. I assume this is some CAD or floor plan tool available for the new iPad. When I checked on the [experience page](http://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/experience/), it didn't show any CAD tool that was specifically used for architectural drawings.

The best I can guess, it may be AutoCAD 360, something from Morpholio, or uMake. None of those look exactly like the demo so I'm a bit stumped.

Does anyone know for certain what app that was in the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the app you're referring to is [BIMx](https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/bimx-building-information/id452706864?mt=8), our building information viewer app that lets you interact with and explore architectural CAD drawing files on iOS.